# External HDD "forgets" partitions

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I have a Samsung Story Station 2TB external HDD. It had several issues in the past, mostly regarding to the short cable that Samsung provided with it. Today, I powered on my computer and booted Xubuntu 14.04 (I had Windows 8.1 and Xubuntu 14.04 in dual-boot), and it said an error about moutning those partitions which were on the external hard drive. I usually store Windows compatible games on it, so I did not care about it. However, I could not see it in Windows, Disk Manager and GParted (on linux) showed it does not contain any partitions. Because Windows 8.1 had several other issues, I reinstalled  the system to Windows 7. After about 30 minutes I repartitioned the drive on Windows 7, The partitions disappeared again. What can cause this problem? Is the drive faulty?

**EDIT**
After a few hours I figured out that this error occurres when I restart the computer, or when the HDD turns itself off when it's not active to save power. Also, when this happens, Disk Manager asks me at the first time to initialize the Hard Drive. I have two options, MBR and GPT.

Comment: what do the SMART stats for the drive say about the disks health? I use Speedfan in windows to check SMART stats.

Comment: I cannot select the drive in Speedfan. HDSentinel cannot receive health data from it, so I have to run a test on it, to see it's status.

Comment: Yes, the drive sounds faulty.

Comment: The test's windows just got frozen when I started it. I closed the processes, restarted the drive, and now HDSentinel and SpeedFan shows maximum health and condition for the drive.

Comment: Try a different USB cable and port, and see if that has any impact. Windows sometimes doesn't quite unmount stuff correctly.

Comment: Sadly I don't have another cable, but I tried it in different ports, because I know the ports have some connection issues when the cables are tense. I have added an update to the post, please read it, may help to you.